# Suppose A is an mxn matrix, if all b is in R m (i.e. A spans R m), is A necessarily independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I think the answer is No. Am I missing something here?:

Note: What I'm saying is that if A is an mxn matrix that is Linearly Independent, A MUST span R m. However, if A spans R m, A isn't necessarily linearly independent. One entails the other, but not vice versa.

My reasoning:

If A is an mxn matrix that spans R m, it seems to me that by spanning R m , A merely needs a pivot in every row (where A is a matrix of mxn size, that is m rows by n columns). This means you can have a case where n > m, in which a pivot exists in each row, but since n > m, there exists at least 1 free variable which entails that at least one non-trivial solution exists for Ax = 0. And thus if A is an mxn matrix which spans R m, A is not necessarily linearly independent. That is, A can (emphasis on the word can) be linearly dependent (and thus not independent), yet still span R m.

Note: By non-trivial I mean that for Ax = 0, there exists at least one element in x which is not 0.

Comment: I believe this much more concise question is what I was asking: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130317171927AA41YHR

It appears to me that spanning does not entail indepences, nor does indepence entail spanning. The only case where either entails the other is if n = m. Where n and m are the lengths of an mxn matrix. In such a case spanning m entails independence, and independence entails spanning m.
Any input here whatsoever would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more precise with your statements. When you say $A$ is independent, do you mean the rows are independent or the columns are independent?

Just some background which I'm putting just to clarify something:
For a non square matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ it is **impossible** for both the rows to all be independent and the columns to all be independent. If $m>n$, then it is impossible for all the rows to be independent, but the columns *may* be independent. Also, the rank of $A$ must be between 0 and $n$ inclusive.

To answer your question (as I understand it), if $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ , i.e. $A$ has $m$ rows and $n$ columns, and **the columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^m$** (it doesn't really make sense to say that the matrix spans $\mathbb{R}^m$), then it must be that $m\leq n$. But this doesn't mean that $Ax=0$ does not have a non trivial solution, because we have not showed that the rank of the row space (which is $m$) is less than $n$. If $n=m$, then the row space spans the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and so there is no non trivial solution to $Ax=0$. But, if, as you said, $n>m$, then the null space is non trivial and there are $n-m$ linearly independent solutions to $Ax=0$

Comment: Great post! Indeed I don't know how to word everything properly. You are correct in asserting this. Thank you for clarifying my wording and my understanding of the situation.

Comment: No problem. Remember to learn the definitions and concepts of row space, null space, column space, left-null space, the rank of a matrix, the row rank of a matrix and the column rank of a matrix. These concepts will make linear algebra much easier to grasp. In your question you refer a lot to pivots. For your problem you don't really need to think about pivots, the concepts of rank are much nicer conceptually. You also don't need to talk about $Ax=0$ having a non trivial solution, it is equivalent to say the rank of the nullspace is $>0$ or the nullspace is non-trivial

Comment: I also recommend "Introduction to Linear Algebra" by Gilbert Strang, I think you need it to gain a proper understanding of some concepts.